# Key Value pair for cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am having an image icon which on clicking should navigate to the other page

```
  '        <input type="image" id="dataReview_' + templates[i].dataFileKey + '" title="Data Review" src="Images/datareview.png" style="height: 15px; width: 15px" onclick="dataReview_tasks(this); return false;"/>\n' +
```

In dataReview_tasks() function below

```
 function dataReview_tasks(inputOb)
    {
   var info = new IOInfo(inputObj);
   var id = info.key(0);
   var tdLastDateId = "lastRun_" + id;
   var decoded_lastRunDate = decodeURIComponent(trim($("#" + tdLastDateId).text())).split(" ")[0];
   var lastRunDate = encodeURIComponent(decoded_lastRunDate);
   window.location('<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/DataReviewNEW.aspx") %>');
```

I should be making the ID and the lastRunDate as cookies. How can I approach this.

[image]

I am not sure why it is not holding the value 54 while I am debugging, I am new Javascript and not sure if I am giving them properly in document.cookie Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Cookie syntax is : document.cookie="id=54" so you may need to change the syntax as document.cookie = '"' + $(<%= this.CookieDataFileKey %>) +"=" + id +'"';

Comment: Yes that is what I am giving in my code. The image is what I get when I debug. I am not able to see 54 instead it is just showing $id when I am debugging

Comment: You are seeing it as '$id' because you are appending as a string

Comment: @selvassn I tried the below code it does even show the ID value

Comment: I do not know your project, yet from what you are showing, why not just set it in the Response on the server instead?

Comment: @Lain can you please give me an example, I will give a try

Comment: @user4912134: I assume that you are using asp.net, so check out Response.Cookies.

Comment: @Lain I am new to asp.net, I am little confused. Please help me. We are having these values id in the client side .aspx how do I get them in the .aspx.cs for using Response.Cookies

Comment: @user4912134: Can you post more? Like the whole aspx, where the id comes from and what you would like to achieve with it?

Comment: @Lain I have edited my question above. Please do help me.

Comment: @user4912134: Made you an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I should be making the ID and the lastRunDate as cookies. How can I approach this.

```
function dataReview_tasks(inputOb){
    var info = new IOInfo(inputObj);
    var id = info.key(0);
    var tdLastDateId = "lastRun_" + id;
    var decoded_lastRunDate = decodeURIComponent(trim($("#" + tdLastDateId).text())).split(" ")[0];
    var lastRunDate = encodeURIComponent(decoded_lastRunDate);

    var tCookiename = '<%= this.CookieDataFileKey %>'; //This is your '$DataFileKey' placeholder from codebehind
    var tCookievalue = {id: id, lastRunDate: lastRunDate}; //Since there are two values, we are passing an object.

    //Setting the actual cookie
    document.cookie = [tCookiename, JSON.stringify(tCookievalue)].join('=');

    window.location('<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/DataReviewNEW.aspx") %>')
}

function readCookie(n){
    var tC = document.cookie || '';
    tS = tC.split(n + '=').pop().split(';')[0];
    return JSON.parse(tS)
}

readCookie('$DataFileKey')
```

### Addition

Yes, of course the values can be set seperately:

```
//Settings '$DataFileKey'
document.cookie = ['<%= this.CookieDataFileKey %>', id].join('=');

//Settings '$DataWhatever'
document.cookie = ['<%= this.CookieDateCompleteEnd %>', lastDateRun].join('=');

function readCookie(n){
    return (document.cookie || '').split(n + '=').pop().split(';')[0]
}

readCookie('$DataFileKey')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have two place holders like CookieDataFileKey I have also one for the lastDateRun but CookieDateCompleteEnd. So can I set them separately. So I don't have split them . Also the readCookie function should I be using them in the called page to access the Cookie value?

Comment: Yes, the values can be set seperately - check the edit in my answer. The readCookie() is just an example on how to access the cookie - however you are going to do it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below :

```
document.cookie = "$(<%= this.CookieDataFileKey %>) =" + id +'"';
```

Comment: No I am still seeing like  "$DataFileKey)=" +id+'"'